# Active Data Set in Python pandas

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I am writing a multi threaded script where each thread utilizes the same global data set. I was thinking that I should use a pandas array for this data because for every 'token' in this global data set I need to keep track of 3 things: the value of the token, the time at which I appended it to the data set, and if it has been used in any thread.

My question for you all is how do I actively append to and make changes to a pandas array as each thread accesses it?

I am very unfamiliar with this library, and the examples online are not very helpful for this application of the library.

Any help on this specifically or suggestions on other ways that I could do this would be awesome!

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt that you can safely use Pandas in a multithreaded application, it is [not fully thread-safe](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/gotchas.html?highlight=thread%20safety#thread-safety).

Comment: which library are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

when it comes to parallel dataframes, I think dask is what you are looking for

http://dask.pydata.org/